# The 2020 Nobel Prize in Literature: Louise Glück

Tags: discussion

<sup>This is not exactly a meta *question*, but an announcement that may be of interest to our community.</sup>

Earlier today, the [2020 Nobel Prize in Literature](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/2020/summary/) was awarded to [Louise Glück](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louise_Gl%C3%BCck) for the following reasons as stated by the Nobel committee:

> for her unmistakable poetic voice that with austere beauty makes individual existence universal.

Louise Elisabeth Glück was born on 22 April 1943 in the USA, and received this Nobel Prize aged 77. She was the United States Poet Laureate from 2003 to 2004, and has received various literary prizes and accolades before now. According to Daniel Morris, [an editor of her work](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Poetry_of_Louise_Glu_%CC%88ck.html?id=T51W8MHAJjIC&redir_esc=y):

> Glück's writing most often evades ethnic identification, religious classification, or gendered affiliation. In fact, her poetry often negates critical assessments that affirm identity politics as criteria for literary evaluation. She resists canonization as a hyphenated poet (that is, as a "Jewish-American" poet, or a "feminist" poet, or a "nature" poet), preferring instead to retain an aura of iconoclasm, or in-betweenness.

She is known mostly for her poetry, including a few long book-length poems such as *October* (2004), and she has also written prose essays about poetry. She has spent much of her career in academia, and is currently an adjunct professor at Yale University in the USA.

**Congratulations to the newest Literature Nobel Prize winner!** I suggest we celebrate with some [louise-gluck](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/louise-gluck) questions on Literature SE, even if she's not part of our topic challenges.